# Meteor mongo save/insert numbers are converted to string

Tags: string, mongodb, meteor, insert, converters

I just noticed that whenever saving anything in MongoDB using a predefined variable the data types are changed from Number and Boolean to String

```
Orders = new Mongo.Collection("Orders");
Orders.update({_id:"12345"},{$set:{price:5.5}) //this works

var price = {price: 5.5};
Orders.update({_id:"12345"},{$set:price}); //this is not working anymore in the mongo collection price is saved as String "5.5" not as a number, same goes for Boolean values
```

Can anyone help me in what is going on recently? Changing the whole application to use the first approach is not a solution as I have thousands of updates generated by my code which worked perfectly before.

Comment: can you show how did you defined your order schema in meteor?

Comment: Does this also happen with a new application? If not , what packages are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this when declaring the variable:

```
var price = {price: Number(5.5)};
Orders.update({_id:"12345"},{$set:price});
```

By this way, I think it makes sure that 5.5 indeed is a number when it tries to update the related data. For the booleans you can use `Boolean(true)` as well I guess